# Akka Scala TestKit test PoisonPill message

Tags: scala, testing, akka, testkit

Given that I have a `Supervisor` actor which is injected with a `child` actor how do I send the child a PoisonPill message and test this using TestKit?

Here is my Superivisor.

```
class Supervisor(child: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  ...
  child ! "hello"
  child ! PoisonPill
}
```

here is my test code

```
val probe = TestProbe()
val supervisor = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Supervisor], probe.ref))
probe.expectMsg("hello")
probe.expectMsg(PoisonPill)
```

The problem is that the `PoisonPill` message is not received.
Possibly because the probe is terminated by the `PoisonPill` message?

The assertion fails with

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) 
during expectMsg while waiting for PoisonPill
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this [Testing Actor Systems](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/testing.html) should answer your question:

**Watching Other Actors from Probes**

A TestProbe can register itself for DeathWatch of any other actor:

```
val probe = TestProbe()
probe watch target
target ! PoisonPill
probe.expectTerminated(target)
```

Comment: I used this but then in the end changed my code so that the child stopped itself when done.

Answer (score 2):

In a test case, which extends the testkit, you can use the following code:

```
"receives ShutDown" must {
  "sends PosionPill to other actor" in {
    val other = TestProbe("Other")
    val testee = TestActorRef(new Testee(actor.ref))

    testee ! Testee.ShutDown

    watch(other.ref)
    expectTerminated(other.ref)
  }
}
```